# JLabel with problems

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I want to make a questionary in java. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Chestionar extends JFrame {

public Chestionar() {
    super("Chestionar");
    final int x, y, z;
    x = y = z = 0;
    String ch1;

    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel("Name:");
    JTextField jtf = new JTextField(10);

    ch1 = jtf.getText();

    jp.add(jl);
    jp.add(jtf);

    add(jp);

    JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl1 = new JLabel();
    String s = "Welcome";
    jl1.setText(s);

    jp1.add(jl1);
    add(jp1);

    //first question
    final JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl2 = new JLabel("What is called as the roof of the world? 1.Nepal 2.Tibet etc");  
    final JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            jcb.addItem(i);
        }


        ActionListener alege = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(jcb.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("2")){

                JLabel bine = new JLabel("Right");

                jp2.add(bine);

            } else {

                JLabel gresit = new JLabel("Wrong");

                jp2.add(gresit);

            }


            }
        };


        jcb.addActionListener(alege);
        jp2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jp2.add(jl2);
        jp2.add(jcb);


    add(jp2);
    setVisible(true);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));
    setSize(600, 600);
}

public static void main(String arg[]) {
    Chestionar ch = new Chestionar();
}
}
```

I want to make to appear that JLabel with "right" or "wrong" that depends on the selected item from `JComboBox`. I don't know why, if a choose an item from `JComboBox` the specific `JLabel` doesn't appear, only if I re-size the main frame.

Comment: Try doing a jp2.repaint() after adding the components

Answer (score 4):

You are adding adding a new `JLabel` to your `JPanel` `jp2` every time an `ActionEvent` is fired for your `JComboBox`. The label won't appear until you resize (or `revalidate` + `repaint`) the panel.

Better to add a single `JLabel` and update this instead by calling `setText`. This approach requires no calls to `repaint`:

```
Integer selectedItem = (Integer) jcb.getSelectedItem();
switch (selectedItem) {
   case 2: // currently using 2 for correct answers...
      answerStatusLabel.setText("Right");
      break;

   default:
      answerStatusLabel.setText("Wrong");
      break;
}
```

Comment: yeah, Reimeus right. and if u want to hide the jLabel, u can set it  like : jlabel.setVisible(false); or jlabel.setText("");

Comment: You don't need to use repaint here as youre updating a single label. `setText` will trigger a repaint in the `JLabel`.

Answer (score 0):

The JLabel must be refreshed. Either do jp2.repaint(), as raven1981 suggested, or call setText like Reimeus suggested.